# Matlab: copyfile from indeces of multiple files

Tags: matlab, file, copy, indices

I want to copy multiple files containing in a source folder in another folder.
Specific files must be copy, and I know their indices in the source folder.

How can I do this? I try use the copyfile, but it works only a filename and a single file.

This is my code:

```
source='\folder';
dest='\folder';
index= [];

 for i = 1:length(index)
        copyfile(index(i),dest)
 end
```

where index is a double array.

Comment: So you have *file1.txt*,*file2.txt*,*file3.txt* and you only want 1 and 3 in the destination folder? Are the file names just the indices or are they always similar? Is the Matlab .m-file in the source or in the destination folder?

Comment: Your example implies that you want to copy to the same folder since `source` and `dest` are the same. Futhermore,`index` is empty. It would be best to create [minimal reproducable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)